# Python iterator function for combinations

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I'm looking for a simple function that generates all possible combinations of a tuple like this:

`t = (1,1,1,1)`

Output: `[(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to give it a better name:

```
def huh(numbers):
    all_numbers = []
    for num in numbers:
    all_numbers.extend(range(num+1))
    all_numbers = list(set(itertools.permutations(all_numbers, len(numbers))))
    all_numbers.sort()
    return all_numbers
```